# Why a PHP module is not loaded into PHP?

Tags: linux, php, php7, fpm, php-opcache

Showing my case how to debug the problem, that a PHP module is not loaded into PHP.

I use OpenSUSE v42.2 Linux OS, with Apache webserver, PHP v7.1, Mysql.

Because it does not provide PHP v7.1 I need, I built PHP v7.1 from source.
Using PHP-FPM.

I installed it into

```
/opt/php-7.1/
```

php.ini is in:

```
/opt/php-7.1/lib/php.ini
```

I find, that opcache is installed to

```
/opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so
```

I edited php.ini and added the following line:

```
zend_extension=/opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.so
```

Restarted:

```
systemctl restart php-7.1-fpm.service
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

But still I get the following result:

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

The opcache is missing from [Zend Modules].

But in configure there is '--enable-opcache':

> php -i | grep -i opcache

> Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/opt/php-7.1' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-zlib-dir' '--with-freetype-dir'
> '--enable-mbstring' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-soap'
> '--enable-intl' '--enable-calendar' '--with-curl' '--with-mcrypt'
> '--with-gd' '--with-pgsql' '--disable-rpath'
> '--enable-inline-optimization' '--with-bz2' '--with-zlib'
> '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm'
> '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-exif' '--enable-bcmath'
> '--with-mhash' '--enable-zip' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-pdo-mysql'
> '--with-mysqli' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock'
> '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-webp-dir=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr'
> '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-openssl'
> '--with-fpm-user=wwwrun' '--with-fpm-group=www' '--with-libdir=lib64'
> '--enable-ftp' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-kerberos'
> '--with-gettext' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl' '--enable-opcache'
> '--enable-fpm'

I also tried to specify as:

```
zend_extension=opcache
```

but I got the same result, opcache still missing.

How to fix to have opcache enabled?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the affected module was the `opcache` PHP module.

**Solution:**

I noticed, that within phpinfo the "display_errors" Local value was OFF, Master value was ON.
Because Master value comes from php.ini, and in `/opt/php-7.1/lib/php.ini` had "`display_errors = Off`", it means this php.ini is not loaded.

Also found, that the "`Loaded Configuration File`" field value is empty, so it also shows php.ini is not loaded.

But the php.ini is located (and should have been loaded from): `/opt/php-7.1/lib/php.ini`.

Furthermore I noticed, that within phpinfo the "`Configuration File (php.ini) Path`" is set to: "`/opt/php-7.1/lib64`"
So it means the php.ini should be located at `/opt/php-7.1/lib64/` directory.

**Step1 fix:**

```
copy php.ini 
from 
/opt/php-7.1/lib/php.ini
to
/opt/php-7.1/lib64/php.ini
```

In command line:

```
cp -p /opt/php-7.1/lib/php.ini /opt/php-7.1/lib64/php.ini
```

Also noticed, that php was compiled with `'--with-libdir=lib64'` argument.

This will likely mean, that "opcache.so" file should be found under this directory.

Currently "opcache.so" is located in directory: "`/opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/`".
I supposed placing the "opcache.so" to "`/opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/`" would be enough.
That became the final fix.

**Step2 fix:**

```
copy opcache.a & opcache.so
from 
/opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/
to
/opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/
```

In command line:

```
cp -p /opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/opcache.* /opt/php-7.1/lib64/extensions/
```

**Step3 fix:**

Restart Apache & PHP-FPM (optionally, if used):

```
service apache2 restart
service php-7.1-fpm restart
```

After doing these 3 fix steps, the PHP `opcache module is loaded successfully`.

**Result:**

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```